# "File has a different computed hash than specified in manifest" error when signing the EXE

Tags: c#, msbuild, clickonce, msbuild-task

My ClickOnce installation fails with an error:

> File, WindowsFormsProject.exe, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest.

I use MSBuild to generate ClickOnce deployment package. The relevant line from the build script:

```
<MSBuild Targets="Publish"
         Projects="WindowsFormsProject.csproj"
         ContinueOnError="false" />
```

The WindowsFormsProject.csproj has a Post-Build step that signs the executable, as follows:

```
signtool sign /a $(ProjectDir)\obj\$(PlatformName)\$(ConfigurationName)\$(TargetFileName)
```

The trouble is, when I look at the build log I see that the manifest is generated BEFORE the Post-Build event executes. So it's not surprising that hash codes don't match. The relevant lines from the build log:

> _CopyManifestFiles:
>
> WindowsFormsProject -> ...\WindowsFormsProject.application
>
> ...
>
> PostBuildEvent:
>
> Successfully signed: ...\WindowsFormsProject.exe

So, the questions are:

1. Is there a way to sign the assembly BEFORE the manifest is generated during the <MSBuild> task?
2. Is there a way to re-generate the manifest (and manifest only) after the build is complete so that hash codes match again?

Or, if you can think of a different solution to the problem, I'd appreciate your ideas.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using MSBuild 4, you can use **AfterTargets** property to sign assembly just after it was created and before any further steps will be taken. Remove your post-build step and add this block to your project instead:

```
<Target Name="SignOutput" AfterTargets ="CoreCompile">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TimestampServerUrl>http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll</TimestampServerUrl>
  <ApplicationDescription>Foo bar</ApplicationDescription>
  <SigningCertificateCriteria>/sha1 578a9486f10ed1118f2b5f428afb842e3f374793</SigningCertificateCriteria>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <SignableFiles Include="$(ProjectDir)obj\$(PlatformName)\$(ConfigurationName)\$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <GetFrameworkSdkPath>
          <Output
              TaskParameter="Path"
              PropertyName="SdkPath" />
  </GetFrameworkSdkPath>
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(SdkPath)bin\signtool&quot; sign $(SigningCertificateCriteria) /d &quot;$(ApplicationDescription)&quot; /t &quot;$(TimestampServerUrl)&quot; &quot;%(SignableFiles.Identity)&quot;" />
</Target>
```

Comment: In case anybody makes the same mistake I did ... I interpreted this answer `Postbuild` with `Target`. This is incorrect. 'Target` should be at the project level.

Answer (score 3):

The credit goes to Dmitriy for his answer.  However I had to make slight changes to Dmitry's answer to make it work for me.  Specifically:

- I added an ending tag for "Target"
- I am using Windows 8.1, and had to change the signtool.exe path
- I am using a PFX file and had to specify the password
- I didn't need to add all of the info he provided

Please modify the values for "my_signing_file.pfx", "mypassword", "myexe.exe" and to make this work for you:

```
<Target Name="SignOutput" AfterTargets="CoreCompile">
<Exec Command="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\signtool.exe&quot; sign /f &quot;$(ProjectDir)my_signing_file.pfx&quot; /p mypassword &quot;$(ProjectDir)obj\$(ConfigurationName)\myexe.exe&quot;" />
</Target>
```

Comment: What file does this go into?

Comment: The project file (*.csproj)

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the signing process of the assembly and the ClickOnce manifest from VisualStudio:

1. Right click your project > properties > Signing.
2. Check "Sign the ClickOnce Manifest" and select the certificate you want to use.
3. Check "Sign the assembly" and select the certificate you want to use.
4. Save all the changes and publish again.

All these settings will be valid when you build using MsBuild.

**Note:** You can generate your self-signed certificate from that screen if required.

**Note 2:** Remember that you have TWO manifests "Application Manifest" and "Deployment Manifest" both must be signed with the same certificate.

If you need to re-sign your manifests at any time after the build you can use [Mage.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te(v=vs.110).aspx).