# Using Authenticode with a ClickOnce WPF application

Tags: wpf, clickonce, authenticode

All right, I'm not doing something right, and I need some help. Here's what's happening:

1. I have a "real" Authenticode certificate from [Comodo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comodo_Group) that I have paid for.
2. I'm trying to sign and deploy a WPF application written in Visual Studio 2012 and .NET 4.5.
3. In the properties of the project, I have checked "Sign the ClickOnce manifests" and have chosen my certificate.
4. I'm also using Comodo's timestamp sever (http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode)
5. In the Publish tab and under the Prerequisites button, I have checked "Create setup program to install prerequisite components".

When I build and publish, everything works! The setup.exe is signed with my Comodo certificate, so that's good. Also, the `.application` file is signed with the Comodo certificate and my company name shows as the publisher -- this is also good.

Here comes the problem: Once the application is downloaded to the client, Windows 8 throws up a warning about an untrusted program (MyProgram.exe) and the publisher is not my company name. So, everything is getting signed *except for the actual executable.*

I've tried adding a post-build script that uses signtool.exe on obj\Release\MyProgram.exe, but when I try to install the application, I get a manifest error stating that the hash values don't match. In other words, the manifest is getting generated before the post-build event.

How do I sign my .exe and maintain the ClickOnce manifest's integrity? Is there a simple way to do this or do I have to use mage.exe on every file, by hand (I hope not)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, no one has jumped on this, but thankfully, I figured it out!

Thanks to this question: ["File has a different computed hash than specified in manifest" error when signing the EXE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521642/file-has-a-different-computed-hash-than-specified-in-manifest-error-when-signi)

I was able to edit the project file's XML (Unload the project, then choose "Edit myproject.csproj")  and added:

```
  <Target Name="SignOutput" AfterTargets="CoreCompile">
<PropertyGroup>
  <TimestampServerUrl>http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode</TimestampServerUrl>
  <ApplicationDescription>My Project Friendly Name</ApplicationDescription>
  <SigningCertificateCriteria>/n MyCertName</SigningCertificateCriteria>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <SignableFiles Include="$(ProjectDir)obj\$(ConfigurationName)\$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)" />
</ItemGroup>
<GetFrameworkSdkPath>
  <Output TaskParameter="Path" PropertyName="SdkPath" />
</GetFrameworkSdkPath>
<Exec Command="&quot;$(SdkPath)bin\signtool&quot; sign $(SigningCertificateCriteria) /d &quot;$(ApplicationDescription)&quot; /t &quot;$(TimestampServerUrl)&quot; &quot;%(SignableFiles.Identity)&quot;" />
```

I had to move the signtool.exe file into the SDK folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin, in my case), but after that it worked like a charm!

I hope this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: I've been using the Post-build event for years. Ran into this issue switching to VS2012. I tried this method - but I'm still getting "has a different computed hash than specified in manifest."

Comment: Scratch that... I somehow forgot to remove the old PostBuild signtool call!  Thanks Jason.

Comment: Awesome, dude, thanks!!  You forgot the /Target closing tag, but that's nit-picking isn't it? :-)