# How do I sign my WPF app?

Tags: wpf, hash, clickonce, sign, pfx

## The question/request

Can you give an example/reference on how to create a new WPF app, sign the clickonce manifest and assembly, deploy it, and install WITHOUT getting the following errors?

*+ Application manifest has either a different computed hash than the one specified or no hash specified at all.*

*+ File, WPFSigning.exe.manifest, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest.*

### Details

I have just created a brand new WPF test app. But when I "Sign the ClickOnce manifest" and "Sign the assembly" and "Publish Now", I get in trouble.

The build files goes into my MVC 5 app, and I publish that to azure. When I click install, the setup.exe downloads, and when I run it, I get the message *Application validation did not succed*. If I check the details log, I get this error message:

```
Application manifest has either a different computed hash than the one specified or no hash specified at all.
```

I have no idea where things go wrong from here. But let me explain what I have tried so far to fix the error.

### What I have tried so far

Here is a screen shot of my project setup.

[image]

You can try to download my test app and install it [here](http://wpfsigning.azurewebsites.net/Install/index.html) (note this link will expire soon, as I only has it as a temp test app).

Feel free to clone/look at my code [here](https://github.com/MartinJHammer/wpfsigning) (also a temp link).

I'm on windows 10, Visual Studio 2015 Community.

***Specific things I have tried***

- Created my own pfx file.
- Added a server timestamp > http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll
- Set the "applicationRequestMinimum" to minumum. [See source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050478/how-do-i-create-edit-a-manifest-file)
- Set up AfterCompiling pr. [this guide](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2013/04/14/windows-8-and-clickonce-the-definitive-answer-revisited/). I also used these SO resources as reference:

  [“File has a different computed hash than specified in manifest” error when signing the EXE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521642/file-has-a-different-computed-hash-than-specified-in-manifest-error-when-signi)

  [Clickonce signed application fails with “has a different computed hash than specified in manifest”. Mage fails to resolve issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487515/clickonce-signed-application-fails-with-has-a-different-computed-hash-than-spec)
- Changed ""Embed manifest with default settings" to "Create application without a manifest" under the Project > Properties > Application. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337458/error-deploying-clickonce-application-reference-in-the-manifest-does-not-match)

None of these changed the error message.

***Specific things I consider trying***

- Manually signing my manifest with [Mage.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te.aspx)

#### *Update*

Here is a side by side comparison of the auto generated app.application and app.application.manifest files. Some of their values are identical, while some, for example the ***Hash*** is different. Red arrows are where the values are different, green where they match.

Is that good?

[Click here for enlarged picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhwbt.png)

[image]